# How to calculate the diff between values of 2 adjacent values across every column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, stock

I made a dataset of shape `(252,60)` by concatenating the `['Close']` columns of every stock of the Sensex-30 index, and making columns by shifting each `['Close']` column by 1 level down. Here I wanted to count the difference between the shifted price and current price for every day and every stock, I tried to do so in a colab notebook, but I get an error as `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

The dataset and code is too long to be shown, so you can look at it at this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i1mEWviSSV3I_PPY6dyOp7QHGDTHfveU?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please do not attach codes in links and provide a minimum reproducible example for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing your code,  I find the below works

```
import requests
df = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in ['RELIANCE','INFY','HCLTECH','TCS','BAJAJ-AUTO',
         'TITAN','LT','NESTLEIND','TECHM','ASIANPAINT',
         'M&M','ICICIBANK','POWERGRID','HINDUNILVR','SUNPHARMA',
         'TATASTEEL','AXISBANK','SBIN','ULTRACEMCO','BAJAJFINSV',
        'ITC','NTPC','BAJFINANCE','BHARTIARTL','MARUTI',
         'KOTAKBANK','HDFC','HDFCBANK','ONGC','INDUSINDBK']:
    url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/"+stock+".BO?period1=1577110559&period2=1608732959&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content), index_col="Date")
                    .loc[:,"Close"]
                    .to_frame().rename(columns={"Close":stock})], axis=1)
    
profit={f"{c}_profit":lambda dfa: dfa[c]-dfa[c].shift(periods=1) for c in df.columns}
df = df.assign(**profit)
df.shape
```

### output

```
(252, 60)
```